# How do I load javascript only on pages with CiviCRM loaded on them?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to load a civicrm function. What is the recommended way to load 'CRM' checking that it is available on the page first?

```
CRM.$(function ($) {
  'use strict';

   ...

  addObserverFormErrors();
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've wrapped it with try / catch

```
try {
  CRM.$(function ($) {
  )(CRM);
} catch (e) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to [create a CiviCRM extension](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/extensions/) that implements either the [pageRun](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_pageRun/) or [buildForm](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/hooks/hook_civicrm_buildForm/) hook, which then checks which page you are on and loads the JavaScript file.

If your JavaScript needs to check for special variables or other data, it will be easier to use `addVars` to load the variable correctly, instead of relying on DOM hacks.

Otherwise I guess you could check if:

```
if (typeof CRM != 'undefined') {
  // ...
}
```